# Calculate density and cumulative distribution of: Y = X1 - X2

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Hi I have this question in my book (preparing for the exam) and I can't seem to find the answer..

X1 and X2 are independent and identically distributed. They are continuous and uniform over [-1,1].

Now I need to find the density function and cumulative distribution for Y = X1 - X2

So what I have is (not much):

fx_i(x_i) = Piecewise(1/2 for [-1,1], 0 everywhere else)
Fx_i(x_i) = Piecewise(1 for [-1,+inf[, (x+1)/2 for [-1,1], 0 everywhere else)

So to start with Fy..

Fy = Prob[Y <= y] = Prob[X1-X2 <= x1-x2] and.. I'm stuck ^^

EDIT - I got a bit further along on myself.. but still not there yet ^^

```
Fy = Prob[X1-X2 <= y] 
= int(Prob[X1 <= y+x2 and x2 <= X2 <= x2 + dx2]
= int(Prob[X1 <= y+x2 ] . fX2(x2) dx2)
= int(Fx1(y+x2) . fx2(x2) dx2)
= int(fx2(x2) dx2, x2=a..b).int(fx1(x1),x1=c..d)
```

Now I thoght the boundries should be a = -inf, b = +inf, c = -inf, d=y+x2
I'm sure d is correct, but I'm quite uncertain about a,b and c..

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it. Clearly $Y$ takes values in $[-2,2]$ and for $h$ a bounded mesurable function
$$ \mathbb E (h (Y)) = \int_{-2}^2 h(y) f_Y(y) dy = \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 h(x_1 - x_2) f(x_1) f(x_2) dx_1 dx_2.  $$
Here $f$ is the density of $X_1$ and $f_Y$ is the density you are looking for. Now do the change of variable $y = x_1 - x_2$ starting from the right hand side and integrate with respect to $x_2$:
$$ \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 h(x_1 - x_2) f(x_1) f(x_2) dx_1 dx_2 = \int_{-2}^2 \int_{-1}^1 h(y) f(y + x_2) f(x_2) dx_2 dy =  \int_{-2}^2 h(y) \left[ \int_{-1}^1 f(y + x_2) f(x_2) dx_2 \right] dy.  $$
Now you deduce by identification
$$ f_Y(y) = \int_{-1}^1 f(y + x) f(x) dx.  $$

Comment: I appreciate the help but could you look at my edit? I tried it myself again and I got almost at the end of the exercise with another method. Could you perhaps look at that to? (I'll also try to understand your explanation, but I know it'll be easier for me to understand if I get how to do it using the method I'm using ^^

Comment: Yes it is correct to write that
$$ F_Y(y) = \int_{-1}^1 F(y + x) f(x) dx  $$
but you cannot write this as the product of to distinct integrals.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that can be solved without any formal integration and limits etc *if you would just draw a simple diagram first.*

- The joint density of $X_1$ and $X_2$ has value $\frac{1}{4}$ on the square with opposite vertices $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$.
- $Z = X_1-X_2$ takes on values between $-2$ and $+2$, and so we know that $F_Z(z) = 0$ for $z <-2$ and $F_Z(z) = 1$ for $z \geq 2$.
- For fixed $z, -2 \leq z \leq 2$, draw the line $x_1-x_2 = z$ which will divide the square into two regions, an isoceles right triangle and a pentagon.  Then, 
  $$F_Z(z) = P\{Z \leq z\} = P\{X_1-X_2 \leq z\}$$ is the double integral of the joint density over one of these two regions and which can be found as
  $$\frac{1}{4}\times(\text{area of triangle})~~ \text{or} ~~ 1 - \frac{1}{4}\times(\text{area of triangle})$$
  where the area of the triangle can be found using $\frac{1}{2}\times$(base)$\times$(height) $= \frac{1}{2}\times(\text{base})^2$
  (since it is an isoceles right triangle)
  without setting up a double integral and evaluating it.